# Error in `[.xgb.DMatrix`(x, 0, , drop = FALSE) : unused argument (drop = FALSE) in R

Tags: r, time, time-series, xgboost, forecast

I'm using xgboost for time series forecast, and them I run train function it give me this error: Error in `[.xgb.DMatrix`(x, 0, , drop = FALSE) :    unused argument (drop = FALSE)

The code:

```
data <- economics %>% dplyr::select(date, unemploy)

extended_data <- data %>% 
  rbind(tibble::tibble(date = seq(from = lubridate::as_date("2015-05-01"),
                                  by = "month", length.out = 12), 
                       unemploy = rep(NA, 12)))

extended_data_mod <- extended_data %>%
  dplyr::mutate(., 
                months = lubridate::month(date),
                years = lubridate::year(date))

train <- extended_data_mod[1:nrow(data), ] # initial data

pred <- extended_data_mod[(nrow(data) + 1):nrow(extended_data), ] # extended time index

trainig <- sparse.model.matrix( ~ .-1, data = train)

x_train <- xgboost::xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(train %>%
                                            dplyr::select(months, years)))
x_pred <- xgboost::xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(pred %>% 
                                           dplyr::select(months, years)))

y_train <- train$unemploy


xgb_trcontrol <- caret::trainControl(
  method = "cv", 
  number = 5,
  allowParallel = TRUE, 
  verboseIter = FALSE, 
  returnData = FALSE
)

xgb_grid <- base::expand.grid(
  list(
    nrounds = c(100, 200),
    max_depth = c(10, 15, 20), # maximum depth of a tree
    colsample_bytree = seq(0.5), # subsample ratio of columns when construction each tree
    eta = 0.1, # learning rate
    gamma = 0, # minimum loss reduction
    min_child_weight = 1,  # minimum sum of instance weight (hessian) needed ina child
    subsample = 1 # subsample ratio of the training instances
  ))

xgb_model <- caret::train(
  x_train, y_train,
  trControl = xgb_trcontrol,
  tuneGrid = xgb_grid,
  method = "xgbTree",
  nthread = 1
)
```

I havn't found anything anout that, maybe some have any others implementations or how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in caret. I downgraded the package to caret_6.0-80.tar.gz and it works.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32169272)

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same error. You can remove the `xgboost::xgb.DMatrix` when assigning x and just do

```
as.matrix(train %>%
                                            dplyr::select(months, years))
```

So, it will be like this

```
data <- economics %>% dplyr::select(date, unemploy)

extended_data <- data %>% 
  rbind(tibble::tibble(date = seq(from = lubridate::as_date("2015-05-01"),
                                  by = "month", length.out = 12), 
                       unemploy = rep(NA, 12)))

extended_data_mod <- extended_data %>%
  dplyr::mutate(., 
                months = lubridate::month(date),
                years = lubridate::year(date))

train <- extended_data_mod[1:nrow(data), ] # initial data

pred <- extended_data_mod[(nrow(data) + 1):nrow(extended_data), ] # extended time index

trainig <- sparse.model.matrix( ~ .-1, data = train)

x_train <-  as.matrix(train %>%
                                            dplyr::select(months, years))
x_pred <-  as.matrix(pred %>% 
                                           dplyr::select(months, years))

y_train <- train$unemploy


xgb_trcontrol <- caret::trainControl(
  method = "cv", 
  number = 5,
  allowParallel = TRUE, 
  verboseIter = FALSE, 
  returnData = FALSE
)

xgb_grid <- base::expand.grid(
  list(
    nrounds = c(100, 200),
    max_depth = c(10, 15, 20), # maximum depth of a tree
    colsample_bytree = seq(0.5), # subsample ratio of columns when construction each tree
    eta = 0.1, # learning rate
    gamma = 0, # minimum loss reduction
    min_child_weight = 1,  # minimum sum of instance weight (hessian) needed ina child
    subsample = 1 # subsample ratio of the training instances
  ))

xgb_model <- caret::train(
  x_train, y_train,
  trControl = xgb_trcontrol,
  tuneGrid = xgb_grid,
  method = "xgbTree",
  nthread = 1
)
```